# Foreign Key Generation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I would like to understand following two tables structure and how "OrderId" foreign key is generated:-

Order Table:-

```
public class Order : BaseEntity, IAggregateRoot
    {
        private Order()
        {
            // required by EF
        }

        public Order(string buyerId, Address shipToAddress, List<OrderItem> items)
        {
            Guard.Against.NullOrEmpty(buyerId, nameof(buyerId));
            Guard.Against.Null(shipToAddress, nameof(shipToAddress));
            Guard.Against.Null(items, nameof(items));

            BuyerId = buyerId;
            ShipToAddress = shipToAddress;
            _orderItems = items;
        }
        public string BuyerId { get; private set; }
        private readonly List<OrderItem> _orderItems = new List<OrderItem>();
        public IReadOnlyCollection<OrderItem> OrderItems => _orderItems.AsReadOnly();

        public DateTimeOffset OrderDate { get; private set; } = DateTimeOffset.Now;
        public Address ShipToAddress { get; private set; }

        public decimal Total()
        {
            var total = 0m;
            foreach (var item in _orderItems)
            {
                total = item.UnitPrice * item.Units;
            }
            return total;
        }
    }
```

OrderItem Table

```
public class OrderItem : BaseEntity
    {
        public CatalogItemOrdered ItemOrdered { get; private set; }
        public decimal UnitPrice { get; private set; }
        public int Units { get; private set; }

        protected OrderItem()
        { }

        public OrderItem(CatalogItemOrdered itemOrdered, decimal unitPrice, int units)
        {
            ItemOrdered = itemOrdered;
            UnitPrice = unitPrice;
            Units = units;
        }
    }
```

Order Entity Configuration

```
public class ConfigureOrder : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Order>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Order> builder)
        {
            var navigation = builder.Metadata.FindNavigation(nameof(Order.OrderItems));
            navigation.SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
            builder.OwnsOne(o => o.ShipToAddress);
        }
    }
```

Order Items Entity Configuration

```
public class ConfigureOrderItem : IEntityTypeConfiguration<OrderItem>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<OrderItem> builder)
        {
            builder.OwnsOne(i => i.ItemOrdered);
            builder.Property(oi => oi.UnitPrice).IsRequired(true).HasColumnType("decimal(18,2)");
        }
    }
```

OrderItems Table:-

```
Id(PK)
ItemOrdered_CatalogItemId
ItemOrdered_ProductName
ItemOrdered_PictureUri
UnitPrice
Units
OrderId(FK)
```

Please help me to understand how OrderId(Foreign Key) has been added into the table structure. I have gone through the above codes but could not figure it out how this FK is generated, when i checked migration file OrderId is reflected under constraints!

Comment: I can't see `ProductName`, `PictureUrl` etc. in your `OrderItem` table

Comment: These properties are coming from CatalogItemOrdered, that is fine because they are configured in configureOrderItem entitybuilder. My question is how OrderId(FK) is there in the table since it is no where declare in the project. However migration has this under constraint. Therefore I would like to know how this relationship/association happened based on above models?

Answer (score 0):

The navigation property in your situation is the `OrderItems` property in the `Order` entity. It cannot be mapped to an equivalent data type within the database. EF Core will generate a shadow property for the foreign key named `OrderId`, which will map to a nullable `OrderId` foreign key column in the `OrderItem` table in the database.

From the EF Core [Shadow Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties?view=aspnetcore-2.1) introduction:

> Shadow properties can be created by convention when a relationship is discovered but no foreign key property is found in the dependent entity class. In this case, a shadow foreign key property will be introduced. The shadow foreign key property will be named  (the navigation on the dependent entity, which points to the principal entity, is used for the naming). If the principal key property name includes the name of the navigation property, then the name will just be . If there is no navigation property on the dependent entity, then the principal type name is used in its place.

If I have the models:

```
public class Author
{
    [Key]
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

When I add migration, you could see it generates an `AuthorId` FK:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Books",
    columns: table => new
    {
        BookId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
            .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
        Title = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
        AuthorId = table.Column<int>(nullable: true)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_Books", x => x.BookId);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Books_Authors_AuthorId",
            column: x => x.AuthorId,
            principalTable: "Authors",
            principalColumn: "AuthorId",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
    });
```

For more details, refer to https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/conventions/one-to-many-relationship